# i can't make num rows inside while looping

Tags: php, while-loop, mysql-num-rows

i have tow tables
first table : For products 
Second Table : For Categories

i want to show in browser like this

category1 (20)
category2 (5)
category3 (3)

```
$select_sub_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE ct_id='".$row_main['id']."' ");
while($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub_cat))
{
  $select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."' ");
  $row_num_sub = mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
  $smarty->assign('numb',$row_num_sub);

 $sub_cats[] = $row_sub;
}
$smarty->assign('sub_cats',$sub_cats);
```

Comment: Well the way you have that written you have the number variable overwriting itself with each pass so at best you're going to get the count of the last row in the initial query.

Comment: Please choose one of your questions and remove the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927987/repeat-result-for-num-rows-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$select_sub_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE ct_id='".$row_main['id']."' ");
while($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub_cat))
{
  $select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."' ");
  $smarty->assign('numb',$row_num_sub);

 $sub_cats[] = $row_sub;
 $sub_cats['count']=mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
}
$smarty->assign('sub_cats',$sub_cats);
```

Comment: thnx for ur replay but ur replay doesn't work firstly $sub_cats['counts'] ??? u mean count is field or count order ??? if u mean with count like id with auto increment it doesn't work , i hope to help me in nearly time because i try allot of but i can't make num rows for my wile looping ???

Comment: What I did was just add the field count to your $sub_cats array, what you were doing was overwriting your count field every time the query ran. I gave you the sql answer, see hendrathings for the Smarty bit I don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$select_sub_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE ct_id='".$row_main['id']."' ");
while($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub_cat))
{
  $select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."' ");         
 $sub_cats[] = $row_sub;
 $sub_cats['count']=mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
}
$smarty->assign('sub_cats',$sub_cats);
```

and then call on your smarty :

> {$sub_cats.name} ({$sub_cats.count}) // $sub_cats.name should be 'name' of category