# Repeat Result for num rows in php

Tags: php, while-loop, repeat, mysql-num-rows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i can’t make num rows inside while looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927269/i-cant-make-num-rows-inside-while-looping)

i try allot of to make num rows in while looping to get number of rows for another tables

```
$select_sub_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE ct_id='".$row_main['id']."' LIMIT 8 ");
while($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub_cat))
{
  $select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."'  ");
  while($row_num_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_num_sub))
  {
    $n = mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
    $smarty->assign('n',$n);
  }

 $sub_cats[] = $row_sub;
}
$smarty->assign('sub_cats',$sub_cats);
```

Comment: What is the question?  Your problem is not clear from the post currently.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like [i can't make num rows inside while looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927269/i-cant-make-num-rows-inside-while-looping)

Answer (score 1):

It has no sense to put this lines:

```
$n = mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
$smarty->assign('n',$n);
```

Inside an inner loop.  If you want to display the number of rows of a query via smarty, just make:

```
$select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."' 
$n = mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
$smarty->assign('n',$n);
```

Inside the outer loop and you'll be fine.

Comment: i need to show num rows with result of while looping because i will use it for number of content pllz help me

Comment: any one can help me ? i see every one replay one time only and didn't attention for help the answer ???

Answer (score 1):

mysql_num_rows function is used to count rows in table so it will used before the while-loop.

```
$select_sub_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE ct_id='".$row_main['id']."' LIMIT 8 ");
while($row_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub_cat))
{
  $select_num_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market WHERE sub_cat='".$row_sub['id']."'  ");
  $n = mysql_num_rows($select_num_sub);
  while($row_num_sub = mysql_fetch_array($select_num_sub))
  {

    $smarty->assign('n',$n);
  }

 $sub_cats[] = $row_sub;
}
$smarty->assign('sub_cats',$sub_cats);
```